# Firefox address window greyed out

Tags: firefox

When opening some web pages with Firefox, the address bar text is blanked out by black and grey bars.  Double clicking or scrolling to select the text causes it to reappear.
Running Ubuntu 12.04 on an older Sony Vaio.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a browser graphical glitch. I recommend re-installing Firefox. There can be mismanaged files. Or updating to the latest version (that's version 29 as of now), if you haven't.

If that's not the problem, please provide an image/screenshot of the problem.